# Why does publisher declares queue a in Pika RabbitMQ?

Tags: python, rabbitmq, pika

I have gone through the fundamentals of RabbitMQ. One thing I figured out that a publisher does not directly publish on a queue. The exchange decides on which queue the message should be published based on `routing-key` and type of exchange (code below is using default exchange). I have also found an example code of  publisher.

```
import pika, os, logging
logging.basicConfig()
# Parse CLODUAMQP_URL (fallback to localhost)
url = os.environ.get('CLOUDAMQP_URL', 'amqp://guest:guest@localhost/%2f')
params = pika.URLParameters(url)
params.socket_timeout = 5
connection = pika.BlockingConnection(params)
channel = connection.channel()
channel.queue_declare(queue='pdfprocess')
# send a message
channel.basic_publish(exchange='', routing_key='pdfprocess', body='User information')
print ("[x] Message sent to consumer")
connection.close()
```

In line #9 the queue is being declared. I am a bit confused because the publisher does not have to be aware of the queue. For example if it is using fanout exchange and there are 100 queues with different names, how the consumer know and declare 100 queues?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The consumer can declare the queue and bind it to the exchange when the consumer connects to RabbitMQ. A [fanout exchange](https://www.cloudamqp.com/blog/2015-09-03-part4-rabbitmq-for-beginners-exchanges-routing-keys-bindings.html#fanout-exchange) then copies and routes a received message to all queues bound to it, regardless of routing keys or pattern matching as with direct and topic exchanges.

So no, the publisher does not have to be aware of all queues bound to the exchange. However, the publisher can ensure that the queue exists to ensure that the code will run smoothly, but that is of more importance for other exchange types.

Answer (score 1):

Any client (Publisher or Consumer) can create queues in RabbitMQ. Sometimes you might want the Publisher to create a queue, but for me that is usually the role of the Consumer. The Publisher doesn't need to know where or even whether anything it sends will be consumed.

For example, the Publisher can get an acknowledgement from the RabbitMQ server that a message has been received. The RabbitMQ server can get a acknowledgement from the Consumer when a message is consumed from a Queue.

A Publisher cannot get an acknowledgement of when a message is Consumed from a Queue, it has no visibity of whether the message was routes to zero, one or multiple queues, or whether they were consumed from these queues.